# how to perform mathematical operations with unicode number in python3 or javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, math, unicode, ascii

How to perform mathematical operations with non ascii number
in python3 or javascript,

like this `1 + 1 = 2`, how to perform with unicode number `১+১=২`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "perform mathematical operations"? Please give more details. Mathematical operations are performed with numbers, not strings, and the concept of a "non ascii number" makes little sense: "ascii" is a property of *text*, not numbers. Note that the `int` and `float` constructors happily accept non-standard digits: `int("১")` will return `1`.

Comment: thanks man, i got it, but not solved my problem, i want to sum non ascii numbers and also get output non ascii

Comment: So by "non ascii numbers", I guess you mean strings containing non-ASCII digits? Are these strings coming from a file? From a user? And I assume you again want a non-ASCII string as output?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that `১+২=২` is wrong, I'd point out [unicodedata.decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.decimal). As long as the underlying number system is decimal in nature, this will allow you to turn each non-ascii digit into its numeric value, and from there into its ascii representation if you so desire.

```
import unicodedata
def dec(c):
  try:
    return unicodedata.decimal(c)
  except:
    return c
print(repr(list(map(dec, u"১+২=২"))))
```

will print `[1, '+', 2, '=', 2]`.

Comment: Also, plain old `int` and `float` will happily accept strings containing non-ascii digits (even though they won't accept a Unicode minus sign. Grr.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Oh, that's interesting. Might be worth its own answer, I think.